# preg_replace when using string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following preg_replace function

```
preg_replace('/[\$,Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged]/','',$audibleinnertextpieces)
```

this is my regular expression to replace either the $ or the WHOLE string

```
Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged
```

for some reason it is removing the U in all my strings, I just want to replace if the WHOLE string is found to match `Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged`

Comment: Why box them inside square brackets and make a set?

Comment: Regexs dont work that way. You cant put a whole word in [..]

Comment: Similar answers gathered at once lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions square brackets create a character class which will one single character from any character between the brackets.  So `[abc]` would match either 'a', 'b', or 'c'.

If you want to match `$` or `Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged` then you want alternation, which is accomplished by separating the pieces with a `|`:

```
preg_replace('/\$|Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged/','',$audibleinnertextpieces)
```

Comment: I get that `str_replace` is preferable here, but I think the downvote is a bit much.  This answer is correct and it is the only one that explains what was wrong with the OP's attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `str_replace`

```
str_replace(array('$', 'Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged'), '', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex for these kind of searches. Why not use plain str_replace?

```
$str = str_replace(array('$', 'Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged'), '', $source_string);
```

Comment: So simple that i deleted my answer :3

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead:

```
str_replace(array('$','Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged'),'',$string);
```

If you know the EXACT string that you want replaced, a regular expression is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
$regex = "/\$|Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged/"
```

which will search for either the $ symbol or the entire string.
then just use

```
$result = preg_replace($regex, '' ,$audibleinnertextpieces)
```

Which will strip any of the search terms out

Comment: He wants to replace the WHOLE string "Audio, CD, Audiobook, MP3 Audio, Unabridged"